# What happens what you print the variable of an object in java?

Tags: java

```
public class test
{
        public static void main (String[ ] args )
        {
            TheClass one = new TheClass(); constructor
            TheClass two = new TheClass(str , doubleNum); // I: calling the parameter constructor to //pass: “David William” and 3.5 to the object
            System.out.println( one );   
            System.out.println( two );   

            // call the method staticMethod
            System.out.print(two.staticMethod());
        }
}


class TheClass
{

     private String str;
     private static int intNum = 0;
     private double doubleNum ;


     public TheClass()
     {
          str = "unknown";
          doubleNum = 0.0;
     }

     public TheClass (String s, double d)
     {
          str = s;
          doubleNum = d;
     }

     public static void staticMethod ()
     {
          intNum ++;
     }
}
```

Would it make sense to do "System.out.println( one );" & "System.out.println( two );" since they are only constructors? 
What would the output be for these 2 lines?

Comment: What do you mean by `System.out.println(one);` being a constructor? Also, did you run your code to see what happens?

Comment: it calls the toString() method, just override the toString() method and see the differences :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't defined a `toString()` method, the output of "printing" an instance of you class will be not useful to a human.

Assuming you defined a meaningful `toString()` method, there is nothing wrong with the concept of printing an object just constructed, such as:

```
System.out.println( new TheClass(str , doubleNum) );
```

It just means that you wouldn't have a reference to the object after that line (and thus it would be available for garbage collection).

Try the same code but add this method to your class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return str + " " + doubleNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class has an overridden `toString()` implementation, then that will be used and whatever string is returned by that implementation will be printed out. Otherwise, the JVM will try to see if it can find a `toString()` implementation for an ancestor of that class and use that.

Eventually, that is, if the JVM is not able to find a suitable overridden implemenation of `.toString()`, `Object#toString()` is called (every class in Java derives from `Object`). This results in an output that isn't very useful.